# Blackjack Issue: The below code does not run the else statement rather iterates elif condition again

Tags: python, blackjack

```
def blackjack(a,b,c):
    nums = (a,b,c)
    for (nums) in range(1,21):
        if (a+b+c)<=21:
            return (a+b+c)
        if (a+b+c)>21 & (a==11 or b==11 or c == 11):
            return(a+b+c-10)
        else:
            return('BUST')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either surround the first statement in your second if with parentheses:

```py
def blackjack(a,b,c):
    nums = (a,b,c)
    for (nums) in range(1,21):
        if (a+b+c)<=21:
            return (a+b+c)
        if ((a+b+c)>21) & (a==11 or b==11 or c == 11): #fixed line
            return(a+b+c-10)
        else:
            return('BUST')
```

A more pythonic way is to use the `and` operator. Also consider using if-elif-else as there is no way both first and second if statements will be True at the same time.

Find the fixed code below:

```
def blackjack(a,b,c):
    nums = (a,b,c)
    for (nums) in range(1,21):
        if (a+b+c)<=21:
            return (a+b+c)
        elif (a+b+c)>21 and (a==11 or b==11 or c == 11):
            return(a+b+c-10)
        else:
            return('BUST')
```